# PhoneGap + Sencha Touch 2 + Android 4.0 app is not starting

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

i have developed an application using Sencha Touch 2 PR3 and PhoneGap 1.2. The app is working properly on Android 2.3.x but it wont start on Android 4 (Not in the emulator as well as not on a real device).

The last log outputs:

```
12-16 14:14:54.453: D/DroidGap(760): DroidGap.loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
12-16 14:14:54.453: D/DroidGap(760): DroidGap: url=file:///android_asset/www/index.html baseUrl=file:///android_asset/www/
12-16 14:14:54.633: I/WindowManager(77): createSurface Window{4149c360 Title paused=false}: DRAW NOW PENDING
12-16 14:14:54.633: V/PhoneStatusBar(142): setLightsOn(true)
12-16 14:14:58.244: D/dalvikvm(77): GC_CONCURRENT freed 288K, 10% free 12114K/13383K, paused 4ms+23ms
12-16 14:15:02.914: V/PhoneStatusBar(142): setLightsOn(true)
12-16 14:15:02.984: D/PhoneGapLog(760): mainLaunch
12-16 14:15:02.984: D/PhoneGapLog(760): file:///android_asset/www/app/app.js: Line 2 : mainLaunch
12-16 14:15:02.984: I/Web Console(760): mainLaunch at file:///android_asset/www/app/app.js:2
12-16 14:15:02.984: W/InputManagerService(77): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@414f3ba0
12-16 14:15:03.504: D/chromium(760): Unknown chromium error: -6
12-16 14:15:03.504: D/chromium(760): Unknown chromium error: -6
12-16 14:15:03.504: D/chromium(760): Unknown chromium error: -6
12-16 14:15:03.764: D/dalvikvm(760): GC_CONCURRENT freed 370K, 5% free 10436K/10951K, paused 20ms+5ms
12-16 14:15:03.764: D/webviewglue(760): nativeDestroy view: 0x2b7bd0
```

Any idea where I have to start to look for an error?

Comment: I figured out that the "unknown chormium error" will be thrown while loading the sencha controllers.

Comment: I have no controllers in my app and still it gives such error.

Answer (score 2):

Check the following in the content (they may cause the crash):

- If you have URI's with custom prefix (ex mm://)
- Check if you try to load resources from local file system that do not exist. This may happen if you: Try to load a remote page that contains resources with **relative** URLs via ajax and render it on a page loaded locally (with file: URI prefix). Naturally the browser will try to find those resources locally and due to the bug in WebKit may crash.
- Render page with references to local resources with anchor (#) or question mark (?) in the URL. It may seem that WebKit doesn't like those and crashes....

Check those above and if applies to you try to fix those. This may help...

Comment: I'm not using Sencha but I had a similar "works in 2.3 but not in 4.0" problem using requirejs with PhoneGap. Your last point about anchor and question marks in the url was just what I needed --- I removed 'urlArgs' from the requirejs config and it's working now.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

had similar issue with `PhoneGap 1.2 +` Sencha Touch 2pr2 (2012 January) does work on Android OS 2.3.3 and above ... 
2.1, 2.2 blank screen and some mysterious errors (Ext.Loader etc...)